# a string problem

Tags: c, algorithm

I have been given a problem that I haven't solved yet.
My program need to work like this:

```
Put some string: Hello World Hello World World World
output: 4
```

The program get string and sub-string, the  sub-string need to be found in the string and count the most common sub-string in the string.

I wrote some code but without success..

```
int main()
{
    char string[10];
    int i=0,x=0;
    char find[] = "hello";
    gets(string);
    while(string[i] != 0)
        if(string[i] == find[i]))
             x++;
            printf("%d", x);
    i++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the function `strstr`?

Comment: I'm thinking this should have the `homework` tag

Comment: You should use fgets in place of gets, so that you can specify the length of the buffer.

Comment: @Jeff Its not necessarily homework. Maybe OP is trying to learn C.

Comment: This is a poorly specificed problem.  Is there a limit to the minimum size of the sub string?  If not then "l" is the most common.  What happens when two strings tie - I guess it doesn't matter because we're only interested in the count?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using the string library calls like

char *strstr( const char *s1,  const char *s2)
this returns a pointer to the first instance of string s2 in s1.  Returns a NULL pointer if s2 is not encountered in s1.

You can find a list of them here:
http://www.edcc.edu/faculty/paul.bladek/c_string_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377930/algorithm-to-find-maximum-occurence-of-a-substring), which basically points out that the most common sub-string will be a one character string, in your case 'o'.  It sounds like you might want words instead of strings, in which case just break your string up into words and count those.

Answer (score 0):

Hii,

try it this way

1) Take 1 string, 1 string array and one count array

2) first scan the string. You must use fgets as gets is not safe and even LINUX/UNIX documentation recommends to avoid it due to buffer over flow problem.

3) break the string in to words and store each unique word in the string array.

4) now take one word from the string array and compare it with string and count the occurrence. you better use some lib function like strstr

5) then store corresponding count in the count array

6) in the end scan count array for maximum count which will give you the max count and corresponding word.